# Trying to visually see the swap of elements within array but unable to

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I'm swapping elements within an array in place which's happening with this code successfully.

However, I've encountered an issue. I've browsed the web and reading a lot of places that we should read the `=` from right to left (i.e `arr[i] = arr[j];` and `arr[j] = temp;`.

I'm trying to trace it this way but seems to not make sense to me for some reason.  I've also tried reading `=` sign from left to right but it still doesn't make sense to me.

May somebody please visually show me what's going within for loop swapping?

Here's my code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String []args){
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
    swap(arr);
}

public static void swap(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @shmosel how the swapping is taking place.  Whether to read the = signs from right to left or left to right.

Comment: The expression on the right is evaluated and assigned to the variable on the left.

Comment: @shmosel yes that's what I thought but when I trace it that way, it doesn't make sense to me hence why I need to see it visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `arr[i]` is `x`, `arr[j]` is `y` and `temp` is as is. Here's the sequence:

1. Assign the value of `x` to `temp`
2. Assign the value of `y` to `x`

At this stage, `x` has the value of `y`, and its original value is overwritten.

3. Assign the original value of `x` which is saved in `temp` to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what‘s going on is the following: You swap the `i`-th element of the array `arr` with the `i + 1`-th (= `j`-th) element. You do this by assigning the value of `arr[i]` to a temporary variable `temp` and then later assigning this value to `arr[j]`. You do have to do this extra step, because if you would just have done the following:

```
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[i];
```

You would have assigned the value of `arr[j]` to `arr[i]` and then have assigned `arr[i]` (which has the value of `arr[j]`) to `arr[j]`, so it would just have stayed the same all the time.

So you need to read the assignment-operator `=` as „the value on the right is the new value on the left“, or „the value on the right is assigned to the variable on the left“, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

First understand what "number is associated with each element in the array.
An element is the place that your data is stored, in this instance an integer.
Your array {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
  element 0 ^  ^   ^
      element 1 ^   ^
           element 2 ^
And so on.

`int temp = arr[i]` so we know i = 0 and the 0 element in the array is 1 so temp equals 1

`arr[i] = arr[j]` we know `i = 0`(zeroth element in array) & `j = 1`(first element in array) so we are going to set the zeroth element in the array to whatever lies in the first element. So in this case 2 lies in the first element so your array becomes. {2, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Since temp still holds that '1' that was originally in the array we set the first element in the array to '1'. In short the 2 becomes a 0.

Each time the loop runs i and j are increased by 1 than is just follows the same process.